# Flutter - Add new Widget on click

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm new to flutter and I'm trying to build a rather simple app.
I have this simple (and still in progress) code and I'm trying to add a new Widget every time the user clicks a button.

Here's my code:

```
class ResponsavelProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ResponsavelProfilePageState createState() => new _ResponsavelProfilePageState();
}

class _ResponsavelProfilePageState extends State<ResponsavelProfilePage> {

  int _count = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> _contatos = new List.generate(_count, (int i) => new ContactRow());

    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text(GlobalConstants.appName),
        ),
        body: new LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraint) {
          final _maxHeight = constraint.biggest.height / 3;
          final _biggerFont = TextStyle(fontSize: _maxHeight / 6);

          return new Center(
            child: new Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Nome',
                  ),
                ),
                new Container(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                ),
                new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Data de nascimento',
                  ),
                ),
                new Container(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                ),
                new Row(
                  children: _contatos,
                ),
                new FlatButton(
                    onPressed:  _addNewContactRow,
                  child: new Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
                //new ContactRow()
              ],
            ),
          );
        })
    );
  }

  void _addNewContactRow() {
    setState(() {
      _count = _count + 1;
    });
  }
}

class ContactRow extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _ContactRow();

}

class _ContactRow extends State<ContactRow> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        child:
        new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new TextFormField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Contato',
                ),
              ),
              new Text("Tipo Contato: "),
              new DropdownButton(
                value: _currentContactType,
                items: _dropDownMenuItems,
                onChanged: changedDropDownItem,
              ),
              new Container(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              ),
            ]
        )
    );
  }

  List _contactTypes =
  ["Phone (SMS)", "Phone (Whatsapp)", "Email"];

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _dropDownMenuItems;
  String _currentContactType;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _dropDownMenuItems = getDropDownMenuItems();
    _currentContactType = null;
    super.initState();
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> getDropDownMenuItems() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> items = new List();
    for (String city in _contactTypes) {
      items.add(new DropdownMenuItem(
          value: city,
          child: new Text(city)
      ));
    }
    return items;
  }

  void changedDropDownItem(String selectedCity) {
    setState(() {
      _currentContactType = selectedCity;
    });
  }
}
```

I want to add another ContactRow when the user clicks that Flat Button with addNewContactRow() on onPressed.
I've found the code on addNewContactRow() and the List.generate part on another question here, but I can't make it work.

Can some one please help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just replace Row with ListView.

Also made few changes in Height/width check it out.

The Result :
[image]
The Code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      new MaterialApp(
        home: new ResponsavelProfilePage(),
      ),
    );

class ResponsavelProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ResponsavelProfilePageState createState() =>
      new _ResponsavelProfilePageState();
}

class _ResponsavelProfilePageState extends State<ResponsavelProfilePage> {
  int _count = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> _contatos =
        new List.generate(_count, (int i) => new ContactRow());

    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("NonstopIO"),
        ),
        body: new LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraint) {
          final _maxHeight = constraint.biggest.height / 3;
          final _biggerFont = TextStyle(fontSize: _maxHeight / 6);

          return new Center(
            child: new Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Nome',
                  ),
                ),
                new Container(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                ),
                new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Data de nascimento',
                  ),
                ),
                new Container(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                ),
                new Container(
                  height: 200.0,
                  child: new ListView(
                    children: _contatos,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  ),
                ),
                new FlatButton(
                  onPressed: _addNewContactRow,
                  child: new Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
                //new ContactRow()
              ],
            ),
          );
        }));
  }

  void _addNewContactRow() {
    setState(() {
      _count = _count + 1;
    });
  }
}

class ContactRow extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _ContactRow();
}

class _ContactRow extends State<ContactRow> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        width: 170.0,
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
          new TextFormField(
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Contato',
            ),
          ),
          new Text("Tipo Contato: "),
          new DropdownButton(
            value: _currentContactType,
            items: _dropDownMenuItems,
            onChanged: changedDropDownItem,
          ),
          new Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          ),
        ]));
  }

  List _contactTypes = ["Phone (SMS)", "Phone (Whatsapp)", "Email"];

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _dropDownMenuItems;
  String _currentContactType;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _dropDownMenuItems = getDropDownMenuItems();
    _currentContactType = null;
    super.initState();
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> getDropDownMenuItems() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> items = new List();
    for (String city in _contactTypes) {
      items.add(new DropdownMenuItem(value: city, child: new Text(city)));
    }
    return items;
  }

  void changedDropDownItem(String selectedCity) {
    setState(() {
      _currentContactType = selectedCity;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ajay, thanks this works fine! In my case I made some changes and added ```TextFormField``` inside list. I am not sure how to get controller and input value from list. Can you suggest some way to get that? Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 7):

This is one way to do it

First, let's see what is `children` property of a column.

`List<Widget> children: const <Widget> []`

It is a `List` of Widgets. Since Flutter UI is built in code, we can pass an array of children that we constructed before. No need to declare it in `[]` every time, and this comes handy when you want dynamic children inside `Column` or `Row`

In your builder, you return `Center` widget that wraps the column. since builder is a function, we can do some magic prior to returning our Widget.

Let us first extract the array from the Column itself in one variable:

```
  List<Widget> extractedChildren = <Widget>[
    new TextFormField(
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Nome',
      ),
    ),
    new Container(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    ),
    new TextFormField(
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Data de nascimento',
      ),
    ),
    new Container(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    ),
    new Row(
      children: _contatos,
    ),
    new FlatButton(
      onPressed: _addNewContactRow,
      child: new Icon(Icons.add),
    ),
    //new ContactRow()
  ];
```

Now, this was the column that you had so far. What you want to do right now, looking at your question, is to add one Contact row for each `_count`

So we do simple old school iteration, and for each iteration we add one `ContactRow` to our `List`

```
  for (var i = 0; i < _count; ++i) {
    extractedChildren.add(ContactRow());
  }
```

After we have our List constructed, pass it as an argument to the children.

```
 return new Center(
    child: new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: extractedChildren,
    ),
  );
```

This is just a simple example. Remember All UI is built with pure code and you can apply all your knowledge from code building to it. For example,
we can extract the method to build the children of Column to make it more pretty

```
    child: new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: createChildren(),
    ),
```

Now, instead of creating our List inside the builder method, we would create new method that would return the List iself

```
List<Widget> createChildren(){
//same code for creating the list
}
```

Important thing not to forget, but you already have that in your code, is to update the `_count` property inside `setState` so that children get rebuilt with new _count

Comment: I would like to see details in your answer, i.e. describing what you propose.

Comment: Now I can follow your answer. Looks very nice!

Answer (score 0):

Updated the code provided by @Ajay for new Flutter 3.13.0 and Dart 3.1.0

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
  new MaterialApp(
    home: new ResponsavelProfilePage(),
  ),
);

class ResponsavelProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ResponsavelProfilePageState createState() =>
      new _ResponsavelProfilePageState();
}

class _ResponsavelProfilePageState extends State<ResponsavelProfilePage> {
  int _count = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> _contatos =
    new List.generate(_count, (int i) => new ContactRow());

    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("NonstopIO"),
        ),
        body: new LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraint) {
          final _maxHeight = constraint.biggest.height / 3;
          final _biggerFont = TextStyle(fontSize: _maxHeight / 6);

          return new Center(
            child: new Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Nome',
                  ),
                ),
                new Container(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                ),
                new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Data de nascimento',
                  ),
                ),
                new Container(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                ),
                new Container(
                  height: 200.0,
                  child: new ListView(
                    children: _contatos,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  ),
                ),
                new ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _addNewContactRow,
                  child: new Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
                //new ContactRow()
              ],
            ),
          );
        }));
  }

  void _addNewContactRow() {
    setState(() {
      _count = _count + 1;
    });
  }
}

class ContactRow extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _ContactRow();
}

class _ContactRow extends State<ContactRow> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        width: 170.0,
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
          new TextFormField(
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Contato',
            ),
          ),
          new Text("Tipo Contato: "),
          new DropdownButtonFormField(
            value: _currentContactType,
            items: _dropDownMenuItems,
            onChanged: changedDropDownItem,
            // onChanged: (String changedValue) {
            //   newValue=changedValue;
            //   setState(() {
            //     newValue;
            //     print(newValue);
            //   });
            // },
          ),
          new Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          ),
        ]));
  }

  List _contactTypes = ["Phone (SMS)", "Phone (Whatsapp)", "Email"];

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> ?_dropDownMenuItems;
  String ?_currentContactType;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _dropDownMenuItems = getDropDownMenuItems();
    _currentContactType = null;
    super.initState();
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> getDropDownMenuItems() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> items = [];
    for (String city in _contactTypes) {
      items.add(new DropdownMenuItem(value: city, child: new Text(city)));
    }
    return items;
  }

  void changedDropDownItem(String? selectedCity) {
    setState(() {
      _currentContactType = selectedCity;
    });
  }
}
```