# TextFormField controllers in Listview

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

In my code base below, I have a `List` with three `TextFormField`. Onclick of a button I add more `TextFormField` in the list. I was able to achieve the UI part from this stackoverflow blog ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50786936/7505562)).

Not sure how we can track the controller in flutter list.

**Need to make a post API call with all the editText fields in the listview like an array**

Below is the code

```
class CreateVariantMobilePortrait extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CreateVariantMobilePortraitState createState() =>
      _CreateVariantMobilePortraitState();
}

class _CreateVariantMobilePortraitState
    extends State<CreateVariantMobilePortrait> {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  int _count = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var scrWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var scrHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      drawer: AppDrawer(),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.menu, size: 30),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
                  }),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              child: _buildForm(scrWidth, scrHeight),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Form _buildForm(double scrWidth, double height) {
    List<Widget> _testCases =
        new List.generate(_count, (int i) => new CreateTestCase());
    void _addNewTestCaseColumn() {
      setState(() {
        _count = _count + 1;
      });
    }

    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 70),
              child: Text(
                Strings.create_variant_title,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Cardo',
                  fontSize: 35,
                  color: Color(0xff0C2551),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 40, 15),
                child: TextFormField(
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                  validator: (String value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return "Variant Name cannot be empty";
                    } else if (value.length < 4) {
                      return "Variant Name must be at least 3 characters long";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: Strings.variant_name,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      )),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 40, 15),
                child: TextFormField(
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                  validator: (String value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return "Environment cannot be empty";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: Strings.variant_environment,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      )),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 40, 15),
                child: TextFormField(
                  maxLines: null,
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                  // controller: zipCodeController,
                  validator: (String value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return "Please enter the variant description";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: Strings.variant_description,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      )),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 40, 15),
              child: Text(
                Strings.test_cases,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Cardo',
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Color(0xff0C2551),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 5000.0),
            child: new ListView(
              children: _testCases,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 40, 15),
                child: new TextButton(
                  onPressed: _addNewTestCaseColumn,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.add),
                      Text("Add another Test case")
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
                width: scrWidth * 0.85,
                height: 75,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Color(0xff0962ff),
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                      shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15))),
                  child: Text("Create Variant"),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Below is the code for the list item**

```
class CreateTestCase extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _CreateTestCase();
}

class _CreateTestCase extends State<CreateTestCase> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildCreateTestCaseForm();
  }

  Form _buildCreateTestCaseForm() {
    return Form(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 40, 15),
                child: TextFormField(
                  maxLines: null,
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                  validator: (String value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return "Test case name cannot be empty";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: Strings.testcase_name,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      )),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 40, 15),
                child: TextFormField(
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                  validator: (String value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return "Please enter Test case Description";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: Strings.testcase_description,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      )),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 40, 15),
                child: TextFormField(
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                  // controller: zipCodeController,
                  validator: (String value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return "Please enter Test conditions";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: Strings.test_data_conditions,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      )),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 20,
            endIndent: 50,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a list of text editing controller as you create test cases:

```
List<TextEditingController> controllers = [];
List<Widget> _testCases = new List.generate(_count, (int i) {
    final controller = TextEditingController();
    controllers.add(controller); 
    return CreateTestCase(controller: controller); 
});
```

You would have to add `controller` as a parameter for `CreateTestCase`.
`controllers` would probably have to be defined outside the method, as a property of the state.

This is still kinda messy, as if you remove an item from the list it will probably behave weirdly.

This is the easiest solution I could quickly think of for your code, but I would look into separating widgets even further and add a more complex state management solution instead of setState;

Comment: somehow its not working, probably something i am doing wrong.
But i want to know one thing that in my case each item has 3 ```TextFormFields```
will it be able to track based on index value?

Comment: Hi Jose, I tried above changes which you recommended. It didnt work for me